# Изменить количество Best selling

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, wp-theme

использую Woocommerce и тему Storefornt. Не знаете как сделать так чтобы стандартная Home Page Sections > Store Front Best Selling Products отображала не 4 товара, а 16 к примеру.

Comment: Там нет никакой стандартной страницы, насколько я знаю. Разве чт вы из демо скачали. Скорее всего, Best Selling выводится шорткодом, в который надо добавить параметр limit=16

Comment: Не знаю, но вводится не шорткодом. Эту часть главной страницы могу редактировать только через customize.

Comment: Покадите уже хоть что-нибудь, код или экраны кастомайзера. Мы же тут не медиумы.